# Fullcalendar, Make Today Button for current month active

Tags: php, calendar, fullcalendar

Today button disable for current month. when you go next or previous month it appear as active(when click on the TODAY button control goes to current month).

In following code I am showing how to make today button active for current month.

```
 function makeTodaybtnActive()
      {
         $('#calendar button.fc-today-button').removeAttr('disabled');
         $('#calendar button.fc-today-button').removeClass('fc-state-disabled');
       }
```

(where #calendar is fullcalendar id)
call this function when calendar load

```
 $(window).load(function() {
    makeTodaybtnActive();
 });
```

Also in **`eventRender`** function

```
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
          makeTodaybtnActive();
        },
   });
```

When calendar load (page load) that time first code work and when change the month and goes to current month (by clicking today button) then second code make Today button active.

Comment: Your question is not clear, you should mention what result do you expect.

Comment: The 'today' button is made inactive automatically when today's date is visible in the rendered calendar area since there is no point in jumping to 'today' if it is already visible.

Comment: @abhishek I  am not asking question, I am telling how to make active Today button for current.

Comment: @abhishek for this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652876/fullcalendar-when-click-on-today-button-open-popover-of-current-date   i write separate post.

Comment: @smcd, user3273700,  abhishek  This was my client requirement , there i did this

Comment: @smcd...  The activeness of the today button also doesn't automatically refresh itself..  If the calendar is left open over the weekend, Coming back to the calendar it will still be on last week's view and today button will still be disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today button disable for current month. when you go next or previous month it appear as active(when click on the TODAY button control goes to current month).

In following code I am showing how to make today button active for current month.

```
 function makeTodaybtnActive()
      {
         $('#calendar button.fc-today-button').removeAttr('disabled');
         $('#calendar button.fc-today-button').removeClass('fc-state-disabled');
       }
```

(where #calendar is fullcalendar id)
call this function when calendar load

```
 $(window).load(function() {
    makeTodaybtnActive();
 });
```

Also in **`eventRender`** function

```
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
          makeTodaybtnActive();
        },
   });
```

When calendar load (page load) that time first code work and when change the month and goes to current month (by clicking today button) then second code make Today button active.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and instead repeats the code in the question itself. This is NOT how you are supposed to use stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

The 'today' button is made inactive automatically when today's date is visible in the rendered calendar area since there is no point in jumping to 'today' if it is already visible. If you really wish it to be always enabled it is possible https://jsfiddle.net/73b7rva6/

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        eventAfterAllRender: function(view) { /* used this vs viewRender */
            makeTodayButtonActive();
        }
    });

    function makeTodayButtonActive() {
        /* turn off fc-state-disabled class and remove 'disabled' property */
        $('#calendar button.fc-today-button').removeClass('fc-state-disabled').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not asking question . I am telling how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In `FullCalendar`, Today button is disabled automatically when we are on Today's date. please check below code.

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [{
        title: 'Event 1',
        start:  moment().add(1, 'h'),
        end: moment().add(2, 'h'),
        allDay: false
    }], 
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: 'prev title next today',
        right: ''
    },
    timezone:'local',
    defaultDate: '2014-11-15',
    editable: false,
    eventLimit: false,
    firstDay: 6,
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: please let me know if you want something else..it this fix your problem then please accept this answer and UPVote on this.