# Fullcalendar, When click on Today button open popover of current date

Tags: fullcalendar

Today button is disable by default make it first Active.([Fullcalendar, Make Today Button for current month active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645324/fullcalendar-make-today-for-current-month-active))

In following code i am showing how to open popover of current date when click on today button.

Write below code in your script file.

```
$(document).on('click', '.fc-today-button', function(){
                $('#fc-more-'+moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')).click();
        });
```

Modify the Fullcaldar renderMoreLink() , add below line in renderMoreLink()

```
renderMoreLink: function(cell, hiddenSegs){
var custom = moment(cell.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // custsom code
return $('<a class="fc-more" id="fc-more-'+custom+'"/>') added id in <a>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today button is disable by default make it first Active.[Click here for making today button active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645324/fullcalendar-make-today-button-for-current-month-active?noredirect=1#comment66600760_39645324)

In following code i am showing how to open popover of current date when click on today button.

Write below code in your script file.

```
    $(document).on('click', '.fc-today-button', function(){
            $('#fc-more-'+moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')).click();
    });
```

Modify the Fullcaldar renderMoreLink() , add below line in renderMoreLink()

```
 renderMoreLink: function(cell, hiddenSegs){
 var custom = moment(cell.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // custsom code
   return $('<a class="fc-more" id="fc-more-'+custom+'"/>') //added custom id attribute
   }
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.